# FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: linux, docker

I install docker using [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#installing-docker-on-ubuntu). I'm using

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

Even though I excetly followed the steps given I get below error when I issue `docker version` command.

```
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I aleardy referred below, but it does not work for me. Most of the them focus on Mac OS X

[Installing a web application in a Docker container: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558496/installing-a-web-application-in-a-docker-container-dial-unix-var-run-docker-so)

[docker error: /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372781/docker-error-var-run-docker-sock-no-such-file-or-directory)

[Am I trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528337/am-i-trying-to-connect-to-a-tls-enabled-daemon-without-tls)

How can I fix this?

Please see the O/P below

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)   
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/create         
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /auth                      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build                     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /commit                    
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/create             
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load               
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize     
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}    
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}        
DEBU[0000] Registering OPTIONS,                         
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /events                     
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/search              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/get                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/json            
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /info                       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/viz                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json          
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /_ping                      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/json                
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /version                    
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/ps              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes 
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 999                 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver aufs                      
DEBU[0000] Migrating existing containers                
DEBU[0000] Creating images graph                        
DEBU[0000] Restored 0 elements                          
DEBU[0000] Creating repository list                     
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()                    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C POSTROUTING -t nat -s 172.17.42.1/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -F DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -X DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -n -L DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -N DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER] 
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)           
INFO[0000] WARNING: Your kernel does not support cgroup swap limit. 
DEBU[0000] Restarting containers...                     
INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.5.0 a8a31ef; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: aufs 
INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()                     
INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)            
DEBU[0022] Calling GET /version                         
INFO[0022] GET /v1.17/version                           
INFO[0022] +job version()                               
INFO[0022] -job version() = OK (0)
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo docker version`?

Comment: Yes, gives me the same error

Comment: Try running `docker -D -d` and let us know the result.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had similar problem on Ubuntu 14.04, 3.13.0-39-generic
The solution was:

`sudo apt-get install apparmor`

`service docker restart`

Comment: Same problem here. A reboot will fix the issue.

Comment: I do not get why one must install apparmor. Restarting the service seems enough.

Comment: Worked for me. You might want to try to restart the service with sudo.
sudo service docker restart

Comment: I am running in Windows, how can I install apparmor - -

Comment: The key for me was to do the restart of the service

Comment: Yeah, this answer needs a reason on "why" installing apparmor would fix the issue. Downvoted for now.

Comment: Worked for me, but before I try this solution I've checked `/var/log/upstart/docker.log`, which last line showed the message `Shutting down daemon due to errors: Error loading docker apparmor profile: exec: "/sbin/apparmor_parser": stat /sbin/apparmor_parser: no such file or directory ()`. That is the _why_.

Comment: @yuyue007 one does not run docker in windows

Comment: I had to add myself to the docker group in /etc/group.  Then log out and log back in.

Comment: Restart did not work for me, but installing apparmor solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

The problem is that your user has not been added to the docker group.

Try:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker <uname>
```

If you don't want to log in/out from your current shell, run:

```
newgrp docker
```

Comment: Didn't need to intall `apparmor`. This solution works perfectly

Answer (score 30):

This error is because you have not started the docker service. Once you start the service it creates `/var/run/docker.sock` and then the error is resolved.

`sudo service docker start`

Then you can see if the installation is proper or not by `sudo docker info`.

Comment: Thanks @nkt24. I just installed docker and ran into the problem mentioned by the OP your solution saved me time.

Comment: In addition to starting (restarting) the docker daemon, the user may be required to be in the docker group: `sudo adduser <username> docker`

Answer (score 25):

I have Ubuntu 14.04,3.16.0-33-generic. These steps worked for me:

1) Install docker

> wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh

2) Add your user to docker group:

> sudo usermod -aG docker "username"

3) Reboot. I don't know if there is a simple way to avoid reboot.

Before rebooting, nothing of this post nor others worked for me

Comment: Instead of rebooting, just type: `newgrp docker`

Answer (score 8):

1) create a `docker` group

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

2) add `<enter_username>` to the created `docker` group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <enter_username>
```

3) reboot the system

```
sudo reboot
```

4) verify whether running the command using `sudo` is not required anymore

Executing: `docker run hello-world` should result in:

```
[user@host ~]$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker.
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker Hub account:
 https://hub.docker.com

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/userguide/
```

---

### Reference

[Create a docker group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/centos/)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you first install you'll need to use sudo as docker needs to bind to a Unix socket which is owned by root:

`sudo docker version`

if you still get an error, check the service is running:

`sudo service docker start`

If you want to avoid using sudo try creating and adding yourself to a docker group.

`sudo usermod -a -G docker <username>`

To activate this change either do, `newgrp docker` , logout/login or restart your machine. If using `newgrp docker`, you might need to also restart the docker daemon. (`sudo service docker restart`) (Note though that the docker group is equivalent to root...)

(AppArmor my work as it restricts all application access, I have no idea how it would effect Docker)

Docker [manual](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#optional-configurations-for-docker-on-ubuntu) is helpful. Sometimes.

Comment: Worked for me, restart was needed

Answer (score 3):

On OS X, `boot2docker up` outputs:

`To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/thsoft/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376`

Executing these commands solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 21 I had the same issue.  I had installed as `sudo su`.  After I ran `service docker restart` all was well.

Comment: This fixed my problems. The smoking gun for me was that `docker -D -d` gave me `FATA[0000] Shutting down daemon due to errors: open /var/run/docker.pid: permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error with docker and @mrother's answer really works. May be the problem is different, so I just put this for someone's information. I am new here and cannot add comment or vote, so I have to add an answer. The problem is as follows:

> $ docker info
>
> $ FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

So I checked docker daemon with `ps aux|grep docker` and found none.

So I run `docker -d` mannully and got this:

> FATA[0000] Shutting down daemon due to errors: Error loading docker apparmor profile: exit status 1 (Feature buffer full.)

then `sudo apt-get install apparmor` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this on ubuntu 14.04:
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

I tried:

1. sudo usermod -a -G docker yourusername
2. restart shell

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow solution below:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 docker.sock
```

Comment: Even if that does fix this it feels like a bit of a hack - generally setting global write is bad.

Answer (score 0):

On mac 10.9.5 what helps me is running:

```
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop docker daemon
2. sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
3. Start docker daemon

Read more:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17846