# Docker error FATA[0000] on Debian

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I'm trying to run Docker, but it shows this error:

`FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?`

`sudo service docker start` gives this message:

`/etc/init.d/docker: 71: /etc/init.d/docker: cgroupfs_mount: not found`

`docker version` shows this message:

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

I've tried the solutions that are mentioned here:

[FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294286/fata0000-get-http-var-run-docker-sock-v1-17-version-dial-unix-var-run-doc)

That are installing apparmor and adding user to docker group but don't work either.

Before that my PC is on Debian 7.8 with kernel 3.2, and then I upgraded it with kernel 3.16 and performed dist upgrade to Debian 8 since docker cannot run with kernel older than 3.10. is the kernel installation probably causing this issue?